# QGIS 3 GRASS 7 locale warning on Mac

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis

I am having trouble getting Grass 7.2 to work in QGis 3.2. As instructed per kyngchaos, I used the following prepend PATH to get rid of error "env: python3: No such file or directory"

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.2/Programs:`

Now I am getting the following error when trying to run any Grass algorithm, with all algorithms aborting:

**"WARNING: Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale."**

I installed on a fresh MacOS High Sierra 13.6. Before QGIS installation I installed python 3.6 as well as GDAL as per instructions. It seems I am not the only one having this problem, but I have not been able to find any workaround.

**QGIS installation information:**

QGIS version
3.2.0-Bonn
QGIS code branch
Release 3.2
Compiled against Qt
5.9.3
Running against Qt
5.9.3
Compiled against GDAL/OGR
2.2.4
Running against GDAL/OGR
2.2.4
Compiled against GEOS
3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2
Running against GEOS
3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6
PostgreSQL Client Version
9.6.6
SpatiaLite Version
4.4.0-RC0
QWT Version
6.1.3
QScintilla2 Version
2.10.3
PROJ.4 Version
493

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anyone comes back to this: Issue solved in QGIS 3.4.